# Add the sum of from the value select of radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

For instance, radiobutton one = value 1, radiobutton two = value 2.

Here is the code I have:

Script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div[data-role='footer']").prepend('<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>');

    $(".Next").click(function () {

        $.mobile.changePage("#" + $("#Answer").val());
    });

    $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
        var answer = $(this).val();
        $("#Answer").val(answer);

    });
    $('.Answer').live("click", function () {
        var NextQuestionID = $(this).attr('NextQuestionId');
        if (NextQuestionID == '') {
            location.href = "/Surveys/Index";
        }
        $("#survey").load('/Questions/GetQuestion', { Id: NextQuestionID }, function () {
            $('#answerInput').textinput();
            $(".Answer").button();
        });

    });
});
```

and here is my markup:

```
<input type="radio" name="Answer" id="radio-choice-1" value="Question2" />



     <input id="Answer" class="Answer" type="hidden" value="first" />
        <div class="innerspacer">
        <a href="" class="Next" data-theme="d" data-role="button">Next</a> 
</div>
```

How do I assign the radio button as value from 1 to 4 and sum up the value for all the question?

Comment: you should at least provide enough HTML for people to know what it is you want, as well as a better explanation as it relates to the actual html. Also leave out unrelated code like elements being appended to a footer that have no bearing on your question

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on in your question and it is unclear what you want. I'm taking a guess and assuming you have a say 5 radio buttons and you want the 5th radio button value to be the sum of the other 4 values. Is that correct?

Here is an example of doing that: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xPx6a/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="something" value="1">
        A?
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="something" value="3">
        B?
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="something" value="5">
        C?
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="something" value="">
        All?
    </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var choices = $('input[name="something"]');
    var total = 0;
    choices.each(function() {
        var choice = $(this);
        var value = parseInt(choice.val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            total += value;
        }
    });
    choices.filter(':last').val(total);
});
```

You will need to adapt this to your HTML.